# Can mobs that have picked up armor and weapons despawn when it's set to peaceful?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was fighting wither skeletons to collect skulls for beacons when I died being withered away, I couldn't get back because it was hard so I asked my friend who was the world owner to set it to peaceful so I could retrieve my items.
Everything except my full set of enchanted Netherite armor and my enchanted Netherite sword was there, it was't floating in lava as I went down to check with fire resistance.

Why does this happen instead of dropping all the items when the world is set to peaceful?

Comment: @Joachim they did, that's the problem

Comment: @pinckerman Oops, forgot to read the title, I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

This is tagged for Minecraft Java, but it should be true for Bedrock too.
I found this thread on [Minecraft bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-5009):

> Even though their "no despawning" boolean is set true upon picking up item drops (e.g. dead player's inventory), a zombie, zombie pigman, skeleton, or wither skeleton **will still despawn if the game is set to peaceful**.

> Resolution: Works As Intended

So I'm sorry, but when your friend set the world to peaceful you lost your precious items.